# How to use SnowflakeOperator with Airflow

Tags: airflow, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have this super simple DAG with one task that's trying to execute a query on Snowflake

```
    default_args = {
    'owner': 'POC project',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2021, 6, 14),
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5)
}

 query_test = "select current_date() as date;"

 SNOWFLAKE_CONN_ID = """{
    "conn_type": "snowflake",
    "login": "zz__poc",
    "password": "123456",
    "schema": "users",
    "extra": {
        "account": "snf_account_poc",
        "database": "POC_DB",
        "region": "us-east",
        "warehouse": "POC_S_WH"
    }
}"""

dag = DAG(
    dag_id = 'SNOWFLAKE_QUERY',
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval=timedelta(days=1),
    max_active_runs=1,
    catchup=False
)
#
# Connection Test
snowflake = SnowflakeOperator(
    task_id='test_snowflake_connection',
    sql=query_test,
    snowflake_conn_id=SNOWFLAKE_CONN_ID,
    dag=dag
)
```

I'm getting this following error:

```
    {standard_task_runner.py:107} ERROR - Failed to execute job 26 for task test_snowflake_connection (The conn_id `{
        "conn_type": "snowflake",
        "login": "zz__poc",
        "password": "123456",
        "schema": "users",
        "extra": {
            "account": "snf_account_poc",
            "database": "POC_DB",
            "region": "us-east",
            "warehouse": "POC_S_WH"
        }
}` isn't defined; 769
```

)

I'm pretty sure that all Snowflake credentials are correct. Can anyone give an example on how to properly use SnowflakeOperator or explain what the issue is with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`snowflake_conn_id` is expected to get the `conn_id` which will be used to retrieve the connection details from the backend table. It does not expect to get a full defined string of the connection and this is what the error tells you the id you passed is not defined.

To solve your issue you should define a snowflake connection.
There are multiple ways you can do it see the [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-snowflake/stable/connections/snowflake.html) for reference.
For example you can do it from the UI via Admin -> Connections -> choose Snowflake, define the required parameters and assign `conn_id` to represent this connection.

Once the connection is defined you need simply to reference it from your DAG by using the `conn_id` you choose.